# Rust clap re-use same arguments in different subcommand

Tags: rust, clap

Rust Noob here :) using rust clap 3.2.23

I have to 2 subcommands:

1. **generate** (This is responsible for generating item based on input parameters & storing in a backend DB)

```
#[derive(Args, Debug)]
#[clap(group(ArgGroup::new("qwerty").required(true).multiple(true)))]
pub struct GenerateArgs {
    
    #[clap(group = "abc", long = "id", value_name = "ID")]
    id: Option<i64>,

 
    #[clap(group = "abc", long = "regex", value_name = "REGEX")]
    regex: Option<String>,

    #[clap(
        group = "abc",
        long = "start-time",
        required = true,
        value_name = "STARTTIME",
    )]
    start_time: Option<i64>,

    #[clap(
        group = "abc",
        long = "end-time",
        value_name = "ENDTIME",
        required = true,
    )]
    end_time: Option<i64>,

}
```

2. **run** (This is responsible for executing stored in DB using params provided as argument)

```
#[derive(Args, Debug)]
#[clap(group(ArgGroup::new("qwerty").required(true).multiple(true)))]
pub struct RunArgs {
    
    #[clap(group = "abc", long = "run-id", value_name = "RUNID")]
    run_id: Option<i64>,

 
    #[clap(group = "abc", long = "retry", value_name = "RETRY")]
    retry: Option<i64>,

    #[clap(
        group = "abc",
        long = "delay",
        value_name = "DELAY",
    )]
    delay: Option<i64>,

}
```

I want to overload the behavior of the `run` subcommand so that in addition to its own parameters, it can accept the same parameters of the `generate` sub-command.
If the params of `generate` sub-command are provided by users to the `run` subcommand, the system would first generate item, store in DB & then execute the item.
Therefore the user can generate & run in a single command as opposed to two different commands if they should choose to do so.

Do I need to redefine all the parameters supported by `generate` subcommand in `run` subcommand? or is there a way to re-use the parameters? Re-using would help so that I don't need to maintain changes across the two subcommands.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by adding a `GenerateArgs` field to `RunArgs`, decorated with `#[command(flatten)]`:

```
pub struct RunArgs {
    #[command(flatten)]
    generate_args: GenerateArgs,

    // ...
}
```

This assumes that `GenerateArgs` derives `clap::Args`.

Comment: Let me try this. One thing I want to ensure is that every parameter that was required in `generate` subcommand is optional in the `run` command. I think using `generate_args : Option<GenerateArgs>` should suffice?

Comment: @alwaysAStudent I'm not sure why you have required arguments that are `Option<_>` in the first place. If you just remove the `Option` type then it's automatically required.

Comment: Unfortunately, am not able to make all args of `GenerateArgs` as optional when provided along with `RunArgs`. 
I get the error:
``` the trait `clap::Args` is not implemented for `Option<GenerateArgs>``` 

Any suggestions?

Comment: @alwaysAStudent I'm not sure that's directly supported. You may need to derive `clap::Args` manually in this case.